# C# Save multiple file in on server and gather their paths in in one cell , are this possible?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload

here is a script to upload multiple file on server folder and store their path in database, however the path of the images are getting stored in multi Row.

For example: i upload 3 images, 
image1.jpg, image2.jpg, image3.jpg. These images are supposed to get stored in 1 Row 

Now problem is that the path of all 3 images are getting stored under 3 row. the path 
uploads/image1.jpg in row  1 
uploads/image1.jpgimage2.jpg  row2
uploads/image1.jpgimage2.jpgimage3.jpg in row3

i wish that images should get stored in this way:
uploads/image1.jpg*uploads/image1.jpgimage2.jpg*uploads/image1.jpgimage2.jpgimage3.jpg
1-  Multiple File Upload Using JQuery Multifile 
This script :
https://github.com/BoSchatzberg/jfu-CSharp-Example/blob/master/README 
and this is 
html form

    
            
                
                Upload
                Upload files

2-  I modified FileUpload.ashx to save all file paths in dataset to convert it to xml file and finally save it in one cell 
FileUpload.ashx.cs

```
 public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
        {

            if (context.Request.Files.Count == 0)
            {

                //LogRequest("No files sent.");

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("No files received.");

            }
            else
            {
                // create table to save all file paths in on file  
                DataTable DT = new DataTable("FileTable");
                DataColumn dc = new DataColumn("FilePath", typeof(string));
                DT.Columns.Add(dc);

                HttpFileCollection hfc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;

                for (int i = 0; i < hfc.Count; i++)
                {
                    HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[i];
                    if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        DataRow dr = DT.NewRow();
                        System.IO.Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName);
                        dr["FilePath"] = "upload" + hpf.FileName;
                        DT.Rows.Add(dr);
                        hpf.SaveAs(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/Upload") + "\\" + hpf.FileName);
                        string FileName = hpf.FileName;
                        string FileType = hpf.ContentType;
                        int FileSize = hpf.ContentLength;

                context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
                context.Response.Write("{\"name\":\"" + FileName + "\",\"type\":\"" + FileType + "\",\"size\":\"" + FileSize + "\"}");
                    }
                }
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();
                ds.Tables.Add(DT);
                // connect to data base to pass Procedure  ds.GetXml() 
                SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["sundbc"].ToString());

                var cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_SaveFile", conn);
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Connection = conn;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@xmlFile", ds.GetXml());
                 cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                // Data is accessible through the DataReader object here.

                conn.Close();


            }

        }
```

Comment: because you add a new row for each picture ....

Comment: I would advise against storing a list of values in a single row because it will introduce increasing difficulties later.  For example deleting a single image path or sorting the images will require more coding.

Comment: your right because i want  convert it to XML file and store by ds.GetXml() , and then pass it to sql so i can then retrieve it

Comment: What you suggest to me all i want is save multi-file paths in one  cell to easy retrieve it like Facebook image systemvb @Filburt